# Display second recently added carousel in dspace homepage

Tags: carousel, slideshow, dspace

I have the home site "recently added carousel" working fine under JSP interface. I would like to know if I can add another carousel but this must display only items of an specific community (like in "community home") and all these, without causing any effect on the DSpace main carousel